# IoT: integrate face recognition in video camera surveillance

Tags: computer-vision, iot

If there is the office with several video cameras for surveillance, and if there is the software I write that detects and recognizes human faces, then how can I embed/integrate it? I mean, should I access somehow to video cameras and use TCP for transporting photos and etc. What is the process of integrating the software in Internet of Things?

Comment: how is this related to internet of things? not sure what you want. if your question is how to get images from cameras that depends on the camera, its hardware interface and communication protocol. there are too many variants to give you an answer without knowing the infrastructure

Comment: You can fork eavery IP based camera stream(RTSP) to your server and integrate your face recognition service with it .Apply multimedia content search algorithm and play with it. IoT is nothing it's just a connected entity where sink are different input devices like sensor camera etc and output are different actors like car,humans etc. As in your use case you are connecting camera sources to get multimedia content and provide result to surveillance user.

Comment: @Mrityunjay, thanks, that's the kind of answer I'd like to see :)